# Injecting template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have this template, which ends up having a really long, awkward name:

```cpp
template <class A>
struct foo {
    template <class B>
    struct bar {
        template <class L>
        struct baz {
            template <int N>
            class MyTemplate {
            public:
                MyTemplate(A a, B b);
            };
        };
    };
};
```

The nested structure makes sense in the implementation (hidden from this toy example), so I don't want to change it. Now every time I want to use the template, I need to write `foo<int>::bar<float>::baz<float>::MyTemplate<5>`. I know I can do:

```cpp
template <class A, class B, class L, int N>
class MyTemplate_Shortcut : public foo<A>::bar<B>::baz<L>::MyTemplate<N> {
    // ...
};
```

The problem is that the constructor of `MyTemplate` is now hidden. Unfortunately, different instantiations may have different constructor signatures, so it is impossible to write one constructor to call them all. I could also do this:

```cpp
template <class A, class B, class L, int N>
struct MyTemplate_Shortcut { {
    typedef foo<A>::bar<B>::baz<L>::MyTemplate<N> MyTemplate;
};
```

And now I can do `MyTemplate_Shortcut<int, float, float, 5>::MyTemplate`, which is better but not quite perfect. Is there any trick, such as CRTP or similar to inject a constructor of `MyTemplate` into `MyTemplate_Shortcut`? I know that in C++11, there is a simple solution with template alias:

```cpp
template <class A, class B, class L, int N> using MyTemplate_Shortcut =
    foo<A>::bar<B>::baz<L>::MyTemplate<N>;
```

Note that I'm not particularly sure about the syntax as I have not used it before. Is there a non-C++11 way to do this?

Comment: Macros are available in any version of C++. Just saying...

Comment: Can you just use C++11?  Pretty please?  It's almost 2015!

Comment: Yes, a macro would be a solution. The version of C++ that we use is not really up to me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose the following solution, which uses a typedef for shortcutting the nested template classes.

```
...
template <class A, class B, class L, int N>
struct MyTemplate_Shortcut  {
typedef class foo<A>::bar<B>::baz<L>::MyTemplate<N> Type;
};

MyTemplate_Shortcut<int, long, float, 5>::Type instance(5, 17);
```

Comment: This looks the same as one of the OP's original bits of code.